# Java Eclipse - JUnit test expects exception but still fails when exception is

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception

I am writing a test for a method that gets the maximum key value out of a binary search tree. I specifically check what happens when the method is called on an empty tree, in which case, it will throw an exception:

```
public K getMax() throws NoSuchElementException {
    try {
        return root.max();
    } catch (TreeIsEmptyException e) 
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
public void testEmptyMax()
{
    BinaryTree<Integer,String> tree = new BinaryTree<Integer, String>();
    try 
    {
    tree.getMax();
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        assertEquals(e, new NoSuchElementException());
    }
}
```

EDIT: when I remove the try/catch block:

```
@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
public void testEmptyMax()
{
    BinaryTree<Integer,String> tree = new BinaryTree<Integer, String>();
    tree.getMax();
}
```

I still get:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at tree.BinaryTree.getMax(BinaryTree.java:95)
at tests.StudentTests.testEmptyMax(StudentTests.java:60)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

EDIT #2: With other tests removed, here is my test case class:

```
package tests;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import tree.BinaryTree;

public class StudentTests extends TestCase {
//here is where testEmptyMax() goes
}
```

Binary tree class:

```
package tree;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;


public class BinaryTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
    Tree<K, V> root = EmptyTree.getInstance(); //EmptyTree is a Singleton class

     //all other methods removed
     public K getMax() throws NoSuchElementException {
        try {
            return root.max();
        } catch (TreeIsEmptyException e) 
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #3: I discovered that by changing the `import junit.framework.TestCase;` to `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;` the test now passes. Perhaps it has to do with these two libraries defining two different types of assertEquals?

Comment: Afaik for the annotation to work you must not catch the exception.

Comment: and sure thrown exception is not equals to the created one - same type but not same exception

Comment: Firstly, don't catch the exception from your unit test. When using `@Test(expected = ...)`, the test will fail if it *doesn't* throw the exception. Secondly, your code looks like it should work. Could it be you haven't rebuilt your code? Check that you have recompiled everything. If you're using an IDE it should do that for you, but try finding and deleting all `.class` files from your project.

Comment: The `assertEquals` checks the identity of the object (`==`), while the annotation checks that the class can be assigned from the defined class. If you extend from `TestCase` the annotation seems to be ignored (or at least it never tries to verify against the expected exception).